# android maven automation

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

Using the maven android eclipse plugin, is it possible to have a maven configuration that automatically launches the android project (the app) in debug mode, so that eclipse automatically attaches to that process ?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you mean "automatic"? Do you mean using Run As... Android Application? This question needs more detail!

Comment: Well right now, when I use android:deploy, the application is not started automatically in the emulator, and if I manually launch it from the emulator, the breakpoints don't work. Therefore I need to use the "debug the selected process" button in the DDMS view, and thus I need to sleep() the application when it starts, so that I have time to click on that button. This procedure doesn't seem optimal at all, I'd like it to be automatized so that compiling the app automatically launches the app on the emulator, with eclipse attached to it.

Comment: Probably best to raise this as an issue with maven-android-plugin project or on the maven-android-developers mailing list, you'll be more likely to receive an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no feature to launch/run the app from the Maven Android Plugin. There is a feature request to do just that

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=102

and it would be fairly easy to do. I have not had the chance to do it yet. Feel free to implement it as a standalone mojo and submit a pull request. I can definitely pull it in for the 3.0 release.

One thing that is happening though is when you run the instrumentation tests the apk will be deployed as well as the test and a new setting in the testing code allows for waiting for a debugger to connect..

Update:

There is now a run goal that will run your main activity set as launcher in your AndroidManifest and run the application on all connected devices and emulators.

Comment: Update .. there is a pull request now that implements this feature. I will pull this in after some cleanup and it should become available in the 3.0.0-alpha3 release coming up.

Comment: I use 3.0.0-alpha3 and looked at http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-helloandroidexample.html, however ant:run and also even ant:deploy doesn't work on my real device, the only one connected to adb. I get a positive log, but actually the apk is neither installed nor started. Any idea? Here's the end of the log: http://pastebin.com/uBSktjkH which looks all ok as far as I can tell.

Comment: Use a newer version like the latest 3.2.0 and it will work just fine most likely. In fact the log looks ok. Sometimes it helps to do a adb install to see if there is some sort of error that is swallowed.

Comment: Nevermind, it's working now. I might have set the wrong value (false) for <sign><debug>.

Answer (score 1):

Part of what the maven android eclipse plugin does is get your eclipse project setup properly (Build path, etc).  If this is done properly, using eclipse to launch the app in debug mode is the best move.  So you would right click your android project, Debug As, Android Application.

Just because you're using maven doesn't mean every action (especially IDE actions) has to go through a maven command.