# Android Maven plugin - How to start an app automatically after deploying it

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I wondering if there's a way to start an application which was deployed using `mvn install android:deploy` automatically. If this is somehow possible it would speedup development.

Comment: This post might be relevant, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981726/android-maven-automation/7044966, and note that as of version 3.0.0-alpha, you can use android:run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the post: http://www.hrupin.com/2011/06/21/how-to-run-android-application-then-you-use-maven-in-your-project

First you need to add plugin in your POM

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <configuration>
            <executable>${basedir}/scripts/run_app.sh</executable>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

add script in ${basedir}/scripts/ dir with next content:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n your.app.package/.YourMainActivity
```

Command to build and run app

mvn clean install android:deploy; mvn exec:exec

Comment: fyi - on http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev-sect-helloandroidexample.html the target android:run is mentioned, I'd assume it does the same as your script. However, it doesn't work for me with a real device connected.

Comment: just curious: why do you call mvn twice instead of just appending exec:exec at the end of the first mvn call? does it make a difference?

Answer (score 15):

Since `maven-android-plugin` version 3.0.0, you can use:

```
mvn install android:deploy android:run
```

and works perfectly.

Plugin's changelog [here](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog#Maven_Android_Plugin_3.0.0-alpha-3).