# Maven Deploy Error - Android-Maven + Intellij Integration

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea

Currently, I have been successfully developing many android applications and testing it directly in my phone using USB cable.

Right now, as the project getting bigger. I need to integrate our apps using Maven. I use Intellij version 12.1.4 as IDE.

Having look at various sources from google:

1. https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/GettingStarted
2. http://4thline.org/articles/Building%20Android%20applications%20with%20Maven%20and%20IntelliJ.html
3. http://www.ashokgelal.com/2012/12/setting-up-intellij-idea-12-with-maven-actionbarsherlock-roboelectric-androidannotations/

As I successful compile and make a .apk file using my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>co.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>XXX</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>Bisnis Pejantan</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                        <platform>14</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My next objective is, to be able to install .apk file into my phone.
However, when I execute deploy command in Intellij UI.

I got error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project XXX: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project XXX: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
```

As I swim to stackoverflow, I found these possible solutions below but, i didn't find any ***clear and neat*** solution/answer for my problem.

[mvn android:deploy not working (despite success confirmation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266373/mvn-androiddeploy-not-working-despite-success-confirmation)

https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer

**My questions:**

1. How to make Maven **DEPLOY** works smoothly installing automatically my andorid app and executing the app on my Intellij just like the run command? What does it differ with **Install** command?
2. Why does my pom.xml ask for **distributionManagement** element?

**Settings:**

Windows 7 x64

Intellij version 12.1.4

Android SDK API level 18, 16.

Testing phone: Samsung Galaxy Note 2, android level 16.

Maven version 3.0.5

Android maven version 3.6.1

Comment: `package` - creates your desired maven artifact (jar/war/etc) in your `maven_project(or maven_module, depending on your project structure)/target`
`install` - takes the previously created package and puts in `~/.m2/repository`
`deploy` - read the information from <distributionManagement/> and tries to deploy from `~/.m2/repository`
An example would be to deploy your artifact to nexus

Comment: so to solve your problem, you'll need to add <distributionManagement> to your pom.xml. If you just want to create the artifact just run `mvn clean install`

Comment: @AndreiSfat what will it be look like? what kind of url value I should put in? Edit: I am newbie in maven

Comment: where do you want to upload your artifact?